# jquery ui sortable, drag and drop for data assignment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm searching an example using jquery ui sortable, drag and drop for the following scenario

I have 2 columns one contains different number of rows and the other column should act as place holder for data assignment.
What I mean:

```
Column with items to be assigned          the desired item should be dragged here
    ------------------                     ---------------------
    - item1
    ------------------                     ---------------------
    - item2
    ------------------                     ---------------------
    - item3                                 - item4
    ------------------                     ---------------------
```

Comment: @PratheekRebala haters gonna hate :)

Comment: what you mean!! I expect explanation now!!

Comment: I thought we are talking about professional things!

Comment: @fefe The code is pretty well explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery UI's sortable's connected lists feature to do this,

Sortable 1 represents Column 1 and Column 2 is represented by Sortable 2. connect both the lists and set the second list as empty so that users can drag their items onto the list. Also, add a background to the second list so that user knows where to drag the item.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
</ul>
```

The Fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/pxtLj/1/

Source: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists